# ASP MVC async Controller and HttpContext.Cache - Correct Pattern?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, caching, async-await

Given an async action method on an ASP MVC Controller and an async method that gets some data:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    var apiClient = new apiClient();
    var data = await apiClient.GetDataAsync(id);
```

I want GetDataAsync to store the result as a Cache item, so it doesn't have to request from an external api next time.

I can sometimes get this to work by passing in a reference to the cache object, (often inexplicably null even though passed from what I thought was the starting thread. Must not be the starting thread I guess?).

```
var data = await apiClient.GetDataAsync(id, System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache);
```

But I seem to remember that this is not a good idea (something to do with thread safety).

What is the recommended way to handle caching in an async method? Should I move cache handling into the controllers? Seems a shame as it made sense for the cache management to happen closer to the data source.

Comment: Why don't you cache what you get from GetDataAsync instead of having GetDataAsync handling the caching?

Comment: @PauloMorgado that's what I'll probably do in the end. I've added async to existing controllers that have the caching logic at the datasource and would like to avoid having to refactor it all - but as the cache is a web cache I guess it's fine to put it in the controllers, it's just not as DRY.